# Missing dll's referenced by referenced project

Tags: c#, wpf, blazor

I created a Blazor Server .net 6 project that references a 'Common' project part of the solution written in .Net Framework 4.7 (compiled into Common.dll).  This Project Common (common.dll) itself references PresentationCore.dll and System.ServiceModel.

When i run my Blazor Server app I get the following runtime error during execution of code in the Common project:
**Unable to load one or more of the requested types:
Could not load file or assembly 'Presentation Core, Version 4.0.0.0, ...
Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version 4.0.0.0,...**
I
I should mention that when the same code block is executed whilst running my WPF app, it executes without these errors.  Perhaps I should mention, I compile my Web Server to a different directory than the WPF project, but I don't see how this should be an issue?

Shouldn't the included reference to PresentationCore.dll in my 'Common' library project automatically reference this dll no matter if called from a WPF or Blazor app?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Is .Net Framework 4.7 installed on the server?

Comment: Yes, this is a wcf server that has a wcf client and it all works.  Now i'd like to develop a blazor server app that will act like a wcf client except use wcf core.  It seems as though this should be possible, afterall the communication protocol (net.tcp) probably isn't different between .net core and .net framework